# can't edit webparts

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I add web part to a page, chose edit this webpart on popup menu and in editor zone click "ok" but nothing happend. it seems that ok button is completely dead.

thanks for your advice.

Comment: Is this an out of the box web part or a custom one?

Comment: it is about all webparts (custom and out of the box)

Comment: Are there any custom controls in the master page or in the page layout?

Comment: Yes there is a custom control in master page, but it should cause problem for all other pages as well. 
Problem occurs only in those pages that is create from one of my custom web templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% sure that a Javascript issue on your page is causing the issue.

If you are using Internet Explorer, HIT F12, click Script Tab and click Start Debugging. Click the OK button and see if any errors pops up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I did what you wrote Hit F12, clicked Script Tab, Clicked Started Debugging and then I went back to the page and clicked the ok button but no errors pops up.
usualy errors shows on the right pane of the Script tab (if any errors).

Comment: Actually no button works non of buttons work in editorZone.

Comment: Try and remove all the web parts from your page. Then start adding back one by one and test the buttons.

Comment: Also, does this same behaviour occur on other web part pages?

Comment: yes it occurs on other web parts but on only on one of my custom webtempaltes. I have started to check its onet.xml to find something unusual

Comment: When I delete all webparts and add them again, everything works fine. Still I don't know why okbutton (int Editor Webpart) does not work first when I create my website based on my webtemplate.

Comment: Strange. I suggest you have a look at your sharepoint ULS logs to figure out what's wrong with the onet (web template).

Comment: Than you for your advice, I found what was the problem, I a had a custom web part which had a hidden div within this div I had a textbox which had a valition which was not validated currectly. I solve it. thnaks again for you spent your time to write an answer.

Comment: No problems. Please remember to mark the answer as correct if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for the suggestion with the JS.
I looked at the HMTL source of the webpart, disabled (commented-out) the JS section and it works now. I'd suggest the OP to do the same - if he/she understands what JS "does" to HTML :)